# Modelling Tides with trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I'm doing this assignment where I have to model tides with a trigonometric function and one of the question was to explain why trigonometry was a good choice for modelling tides. I know that its partially because tides follow a periodic pattern similar to the sine or cosine function but I was hoping maybe there are more reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Your stated reason is a good one, and I believe is the primary one for dealing with any mathematical model of tides. As Wikipedia's [tide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tide) article says,

> Many shorelines experience [semi-diurnal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-diurnal) tides—two nearly equal high and low tides each day. Other locations have a [diurnal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diurnal_cycle) tide—one high and low tide each day. A "mixed tide"—two uneven magnitude tides a day—is a third regular category.

This indicates the primary tide activity is periodic (although the length of the main period depends to a significant extent on the shoreline location) and, thus, can be modeled relatively well using a trigonometric related function (in particular, using sines and cosines).

The article also states

> While tides are usually the largest source of short-term sea-level fluctuations, sea levels are also subject to forces such as wind and barometric pressure changes ...

The wind and air pressure affect the flow of water, such as with waves, with this sometimes affecting the tidal patterns of a location. Note that waves are often modeled using the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation), with this Wikipedia article saying

> The basic wave equation is a [linear differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) and so it will adhere to the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle). This means that the net displacement caused by two or more waves is the sum of the displacements which would have been caused by each wave individually. In addition, the behavior of a wave can be analyzed by breaking up the wave into components, e.g. the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) breaks up a wave into sinusoidal components.

Thus, once again, the "sinusoidal components" mentioned involve using sines & cosines, i.e., trigonometric functions, in the model's solution.